# Как отправить несколько форм Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Помогите решить такую проблему. 
На странице выводится блоки (количество не ограничено ) , каждый блок это по-сути фора для редактирования даных отдельного юзера, и когда нажимается сабмит то данные отправляются на контроллер и там уже обрабатываются.
Я хочу что б данные отправлялись в таком виде

```
[
  [
    'name' => first,
  ],
  [
      'name' => second,
  ]
]
```

Возможно ли как-то сделать в ActiveForm еще несколько форм, Делаю это так, но формы не отправляются:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => Url::to('/user/'.$employeeType.'/save-information'),
        'id' => 't-form'
]);?>

<?php foreach ($usersCollection as $employee):?>

        <?php $formN = ActiveForm::begin([
              'id' => 't-form'
         ]);?>

             $formN->field($employee, 'name')?>

        <?php ActiveForm::end()?>
  <?php endforeach;?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])?>
<?php ActiveForm::end();?>
```

Усли `id` в форм одинаковые и если разные (или вовсе нет) - формы все равно не отправляются.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить или сделать правильней,**

Спасибо !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В документации по `Yii2` есть хороший пример по работе с [табличным вводом данных](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/input-tabular-input.md)

Главное, что нужно увидеть там - принцип формирования названий полей. Чтобы получить массив моделей, нужно в использовать числовые индексы в названиях атрибутов. Например:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

foreach ($usersCollection as $index => $employee):?>

  <?php $formN = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 't-form']);?>

  <?php echo $formN->field($employee, '[$index]name')?>

  <?php ActiveForm::end()?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Затем, в контроллере можно обработать весь массив, используя методы модели `loadMultiple()` и `validateMultiple()`

Comment: Спасибо большое )